# Problems with posting checkbox data using HttpClient

Tags: java, android, post, httpclient

I'm trying to use the BasicNameValuePair criteria to post checkbox data to a website. My method is sound, as I've used it many other time within the same application. However. I've run into a problem. While normal HTML input elements go by the same scheme as:

```
<INPUT NAME='_user' TYPE='text' SIZE='10'>
```

Where you can input the value of element '_user', this checkbox element goes by:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='cat17' value='true' checked='checked' /> Announcements/Sign-Ups/Deadlines<br/>
```

Where value is *ALWAYS* true, and the value that gets removed/ added on checkbox-click is the attribute "checked." It either gets removed entirely or added entirely, and I haven't found a way to do this using BasicNameValuePair. Thoughts?

I can post my code if needed, but I don't think the problem is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed this frustrating problem.

Used Google Chrome's "Inspect Element" feature to see exactly what was posted to the website when you click the button after checking/unchecking all checkboxes. Saw there was some extra data there that I wasn't posting, namely my username and other random information. Added that to my postData using a BasicNameValuePair, and it worked.